# How to make elements float all the way to the left again?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I think this has been asked a million times, but with different definitions of the problem. And it's probably either easy to fix or a long lasting wish from web designers and still unanswered. **note**: I *did* do a search on css float on stack, but although some look like my problem, so far I haven't found a similar one.

What I'm trying to do will become clear if you see the attachment. I want them in rows of 3 neatly stacked under each other, where the height of each `<li>` item is different. In other words: the heighest `<li>` element in a row is leading, and the next row of items should wrap under this one. Right now the items on the new row bump into the content of a longer list item at the beginning, preventing the first item of the new row to fully float to the left.

Please note that I don't want to solve this with php or js, I think a pure css solution must be out there... Because with php, I could of course add a class like "new-row" to it and apply a `clear: both` to it and it will wrap. If I want to do the same thing in CSS then I can't without using poorly supported `:nth-of-type` stuff. Besides, the content block is variable in width, so sometimes there are 3 on a row and sometimes maybe only 2 or up to 6.

Who can help?

[image: Screenshot from actual website design and flawed css floats]

Comment: Did you try fixing a min-height and use `overflow: visible` property? Just a thought...

Comment: Just tried floating some li's and it worked out as you described, unless I've read this wrong. [http://jsfiddle.net/D46se/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/D46se/1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use "display:inline-block" for LI, not "float:left"

Comment: Here is a great article on this technique: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: Now this _is_ a neat solution to the problem! I think this is the way to create something like this without js and lists. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to be proven wrong, but I think you have to use tables for this, or a `display: table-*` construct. (I personally would go with tables - this *is* somewhat tabular data.)

Only table rendering can resize a whole row according to its tallest member's height.

It's the only way I can see to do this without JS or PHP.

Comment: Yes, I know, tables are probably best for this. But it is coming from a Wordpress plugin and that is giving a `<ul>` which then can be styled with css to the desired layout. Of course I could go in the plugin and transform it in a table output, but that's not the point.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery.

Pretty sure this is impossible using just CSS. Unless you're going to use absolute positioning and forget floats all together.

I hope I am wrong though! :)

(Would love to be able to do this w/ css)

Comment: See Petrov's comment on this, it's an excellent article on doing this with inline-block including hacks for unwilling browsers. Pretty neat!

Comment: It is a cool concept, but it doesn't exactly solve the problem if i'm correct?